# Differences with Rspec syntax eq and to be

Tags: ruby, rspec

I had written a version of fizzbuzz about six months ago and was fairly sure my test coverage at the time was good. I loaded it today and had most of my spec tests failing. Originally i used the syntax to_be true. In order to get the test coverage to be good again i have had to change this syntax to state to eq true. Could anyone explain why this is and that i am still testing correctly?

**Original syntax example**

```
**fizzbuzz_spec.rb**
require 'fizzbuzz'


describe 'FizzBuzz' do 
    context 'it knows that a number is divisible by' do 
        it '3' do 
            expect(is_divisible_by_three?(3)).to be_true
        end
    end
end

**fizzbuzz.rb**
def is_divisible_by_three?(number)
    true
end

**ERROR:**   1) FizzBuzz it knows that a number is divisible by 3
     Failure/Error: expect(is_divisible_by_three?(3)).to be_true
       expected true to respond to `true?`
     # ./spec/fizzbuzz_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**New syntax example**
**fizzbuzz_spec.rb**
    require 'fizzbuzz'

```
describe 'FizzBuzz' do 
    context 'it knows that a number is divisible by' do 
        it '3' do 
            expect(is_divisible_by_three?(3)).to eq true
        end
    end
end

**fizzbuzz.rb**
def is_divisible_by_three?(number)
    true
end
```

I know that i need to expand on the code in the def divisible by method, i am merely using true here as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`be_true` has been [renamed to `be_truthy`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/283) in the most recent versions of RSpec.

Because `be_true` was removed, the spec may fail since the method is no longer there.

The solution is to update the code to use the new method. `eq(true)` works, but it's slightly different: `be_truthy` and `be_falsey` are designed to match true/false-alike values (e.g. nil evaluates to false, but is not equal to false).

If you use `eq(true)` you pretend a strict match.